# Xamarin ios Share Extension is not working

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.mac, ios8-share-extension

I created a simple 'Share Extension' in xamarin ios

However, after tapping my extension icon, then the native share dialog comes up, then I tap 'post' button but, I do not see anything happening after the 'post' button is tapped.

In the DidSelectPost override, I tried AlertView, but nothing seems to be happening, the share dialog goes away.

Comment: please add some code

Comment: i have not write any code yet, i just simply add the alertview in the didload and isContentValid method but nothing is happening.

Comment: You talking about DidLoad, DidSelectPost e.t.c of witch class?
if you give us minimum code to reproduce we can see where is error